# How to supply -s settings.xml as param into pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

What I need is, make a profile in `pom.xml` when I run `mvn test`,  it will actually triggle `mvn clean install -s settings.xml`  ,
this settings.xml is within the project directory root, so it is a customized one, not the .m2/rep default one.
here is my attempt in pom file (following this tut https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_profiles.htm):

```
    ...
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>-s</name>
                <value>settings.xml</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
     ...
```

but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do that. And why would you want to run a completely different command with another settings when running `mvn test`?

Comment: You might (ab)use `invoker:integration-test` to do that... see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html